# Search/index all fields of all tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a Postgres database and an web-interface has been created for it, which allows all tables to be filtered by any fields by different operators (for example, =, >, <, contains, starts, etc. (the set for each field depends on its type)).

Does Postgres have mechanisms to search for any combination of conditions/fields?

Indexing each field (or the total composite gin/gist) is not good, since there are quite large tables with a large number of columns, and each index is 1GB. And this is obtained during write operations.
Full-text, probably, is not very suitable here, since filtering can be quite simple, such as in number, Boolean, etc. And there is no task here in text search.
If a third-party mechanism, it to be so integrated that ordinary sql from any source uses this mechanism for searching.

Share please what are the options so I can quickly (preferably native sql) filter tables by any combination of conditions by any fields.

[filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWxoU.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

This is doomed.

If the table is big enough and has enough columns, then having one index per column will slow down all data modifications quite a lot. On the other hand, if you have a column that is not indexed, some queries might become intolerably slow.

The best way out of this impasse is to change the requirements:

- force the user to enter at least one of a few selective criteria (for example, you must at least enter either the customer number or a narrow timestamp range)
- make sure that these few criteria are well indexed

Then the user may specify as many additional search criteria as she wants, and queries will still always perform well. Make sure there is no `OR` in the `WHERE` condition.

This might be a hard sell, but in the end it will make everybody happier. Nobody wants to wait very long for a search result that then turn out to consist of too many rows than you can handle anyway.

Comment: thank you for answer! It is not possible. Users can filter as they like by any fields and criteria. I added pic about filter: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWxoU.png

Comment: I understand. My answer predicts that you will probably not find a good solution for that.